# Rails first or initialize selecting multiple enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Status is a enum, I need to find the first user that is `waiting` or `declined`, if not one exists, initialize one

The bellow code should work, but is giving me an error:

```
User.where(status: [:waiting, :declined]).first_or_initialize
=> ArgumentError ('[:waiting, :declined]' is not a valid status)
```

I assume it is because status cannot be an array of symbols. I've also tried:

```
User.where(status: [:waiting, :declined]).first_or_initialize({ status: :waiting })
# And 
User.where(status: [:waiting, :declined]).first_or_initialize do |user|
  user.status = :waiting
end
```

But neither one worked.
How can I do this query?

Comment: I guess it's because your searching with two different statuses, and rails can't infer which one to use.

Comment: Have you tried with: `User.where(status: :waiting).or(User.where(status: :declined)).first_or_initialize({status: :waiting})`?

Comment: @fanta That's my guess too. But how can I tell rails which status to use? Both ways should be enough and yet, it does not work

Comment: @MrShemek can you submit your comment as a answer? That did work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work, please use the following code:

```
User.where(status: :waiting).or(User.where(status: :declined)).first_or_initialize({status: :waiting})
```

Maybe it is not the prettiest code but it should work.